# How to configure multiple gradle modules in IntelliJ for Class Navigation?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have 2 independent gradle modules imported into one workspace in intelliJ.
[image]

The **ota** module depends on **metasearch** module. 
In Maven, if **metasearch** module have same version to **metasearch** dependency version in **ota**, I can navigate between classes in these 2 modules.
Currently, when I *go to implementation* classes in **metasearch** from **ota**, it navigates me to classes in **metasearch.jar** file.

How to configure IntelliJ to navigate between inner classes in workspace?

Comment: There is however a hidden option that you may try to set: "external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true" via "Help | Edit Custom Properties" and restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is however a hidden option that you may try to set: "external.system.substitute.library.dependencies = true" via "Help | Edit Custom Properties" and restart.